# p:inputText, p:message and p:commandbutton doesn't show

Tags: jsf

I want to know why the `p:inputText` and the `p:message` and `p:commandbutton` doesn't show, this is my xhtml page:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/facelet/layout.xhtml" >
    <ui:define name="title">login</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="contentLeft">
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="contentCenter">
        <h:form id="mainForm">
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputText style=" width: 100px " value=" login : "/>
                <p:inputText id="j_username" style=" width:200px " value="#{loginCtr.userName}"/>
                <p:message for="j_username" style=" color:red;" />
                <h:outputText style=" width:100px" value="mot de passe :"/>
                <p:inputText id="j_password" style="width:200px" value="#{loginCtr.userPassWord}"/>
                <p:message for="j_password" style="color:red;" />
                <h:column/>
                <p:commandButton action="#{loginCtr.connecter()}" value="se Connecter"/>

            </h:panelGrid>


        </h:form>
        <p:messages autoUpdate="true"></p:messages>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: What HTML is rendered? Do "View source" on the target browser. It is likely that the template path is given a wrong value here `template="/facelet/layout.xhtml"`. BTW, template files should be placed under `WEB-INF` so that they are not accessible by clients.

Comment: think you , it just miss same files .jar thinks :)